# I will be in and out today

Tags: idiom

Is there a term for "in and out" in the sense of: Ich habe Geschäfte und bin deswegen nur zeitweise zu Hause oder im Büro?

Comment: Are you open to reformulation with a different structure?  Then "Bin heute unterbrochen da" or "Ich muss heute ein Paar mal weg" or "Ich bin heute da aber nicht andauernd."  Or do you specifically want a single short phrase to replace only "in and out"?

Comment: ab und zu? just guessing here...

Comment: My bosses often say “Ich schau/komm heute nur kurz rein”, refering to their flying visits at the office and their businesses out of town.

Comment: Wie würde man es denn mit 'in and out' sagen? Zeitweise in and zeitweise out? Mal da und mal nicht?

Answer (score 7):

There’s no special term that I’m aware of right now. If you want to express that your location will vary over the day you could say:

> Ich bin heute geschäftlich **unterwegs** und deshalb schwer zu erreichen.

[*unterwegs*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unterwegs) is a well known and often used word to describe that you are “on the road” and that’s probably the closest to be “in and out”.

**Addition:** As pointed out in the comments, "unterwegs" implies that you are not in the office or at home at all. That could be misleading, so you need some kind of constraint on that.

You could say:

> Ich bin heute **ab und zu** unterwegs und deshalb schlecht zu erreichen.
>
> Ich bin heute **zeitweise** außer Haus/Büro und dann nur schwer zu erreichen.

Both versions would make it clearer that you are in and out this day, but without determining a specific time or timespan.

Comment: I’d understand “Ich bin heute unterwegs” as saying that you aren‘t in the office at all, so it’s not the same as being there from time to time.

Comment: Yeah, you´re right, there´s some room for (mis)interpretation here, I will add that.

Comment: +1 für *zeitweise außer Haus*

Comment: Freut mich, dass es dir gefällt. :-)

Answer (score 3):

What I use quite often in this context is a combination of ***sporadisch*** and the location or ***außer Haus sein*** (to be out, also used for the office).

> Ich bin morgen sporadisch außer Haus *(expecting to be more in than out)*.
>   Ich bin morgen nur sporadisch im Büro *(expecting to be more out than in)*.

Synonyms to replace *[sporadisch](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=sporadisch)* in this context are: *ab und an, ab und zu, des Öfteren, gelegentlich, hin und wieder, manchmal, vereinzelt, von Zeit zu Zeit, zeitweilig, zeitweise, zuweilen*.